# Get the length of the last word in a string

Tags: python, string

I need to write a Python program to only give me the length of the last word in the string.

However, if there is no word in the end, it should return 0.

For example

```
input = 'Hello World'
output = length of World = 5

input = "Hello World '
Output = 5

input = " "
output = 0
```

Comment: What you are asking for here is not a specific problem. Yes, the heading is but the problem isn't. A function to remove leading and trailing spaces from a string in Python is `strip()`. What you asked from us was for us to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

`rsplit` splits string by separator (whitespace) count (1) times.
If there is nothing, `rsplit` returns list with zero-length string (works only with separator). Without separator it's possible to get empty array. More in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

So, you don't have to check before accessing by index.

Then returning length of last item.

```
def last_word_length(string):
    return len(string.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1])
```

Test:

```
print(last_word_length('Hello world'))  # 5
print(last_word_length(' '))            # 0
print(last_word_length(''))             # 0
print(last_word_length('a'))            # 1
```